# Extending Picard-Lindelöf (quick proof check)

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

I am trying to show that, if $F:\;[0,1]\times \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is uniformly Lipschitz continuous in the $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ variables, the system:

$$f^{(n)}(t)=F\big(t,\,f(t),\,\dots,\, f^{(n-1)}(t)\big);\quad f^{(k)}(0)=a_k, \;0\leq k< n$$
Has a unique solution on $[0,\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0$.

**My try**

By the Picard-Lindelöf theorem, the system:

$$f^{(n)}=F\big(t,\,0,\dots \,0,\,f^{(n-1)}(t)\big);\quad f^{(n-1)}(0)=a_{n-1}$$
has a unique solution on $[0,\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0$. Then $f^{(n-2)}$ is determined by $f^{(n-2)}(0)=a_{n-2}$ etc. down to $f$, determined by $f(0)=a_0$. ... Done?

Is that enough, or have I missed something crucial?

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong.
$f^{(n)}(t) = F(t, 0, \ldots, f^{(n-1)}(t))$ is a completely different system
from $f^{(n)}(t) = F(t, f(t), \ldots, f^{(n-1)}(t))$.  There is no way to get
a solution of one from a solution of the other, or in general to solve an $n$'th order differential equation in terms of solutions of first order differential equations.

What you can do, however, is write the $n$'th order differential equation as
a first-order **system**

$$ \dfrac{d}{dt} {\bf x}(t) = {\bf G}(t,{ \bf x}(t))$$
where $$
G(t, {\bf x}) = \pmatrix{ x_2\cr
                        \ldots\cr
                         x_n\cr
                         F(t,x_1, \ldots, x_n)\cr}$$

Comment: Ok thank you - and is $\mathbf{G}$ uniformly Lipschitz continuous in $\mathbf{x}$ because $F$ is? Sorry I am just a bit confused about all this, it's still very new.